# Fill in DC.JS Heat Map gap with default or calculated value

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Is it possible to easily fill in gaps within a HeatMap chart that are not given values in the data source? The problem I'm having is illustrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/qk94cuaq/.

```js
var data = [{Expt: 1,Run: 1, Speed: 850},
{Expt: 1,Run: 2, Speed: 740},
{Expt: 2,Run: 2, Speed: 940},
{Expt: 3,Run: 1, Speed: 880},
{Expt: 3,Run: 3, Speed: 880},];

var chart = dc.heatMap("#test");

var ndx = crossfilter(data),
    runDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.Run, +d.Expt];
    }),
    runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return +d.Speed;
    });

chart.width(45 * 4 + 80)
    .height(45 * 4 + 40)
    .dimension(runDim)
    .group(runGroup)
    .keyAccessor(function (d) {
    return +d.key[0];
})
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
    return +d.key[1];
})
    .colorAccessor(function (d) {
    return +d.value;
})
    .colors(["#ffffd9", "#edf8b1", "#c7e9b4",
    "#7fcdbb", "#41b6c4", "#1d91c0", "#225ea8", "#253494", "#081d58"])
    .calculateColorDomain();

chart.render();
```

```html
<link href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/css/dc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.11/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
<body>
     <h2> Heat Map Testing </h2>

    <div id="test" class="dc-chart"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do it would be to probably extend dc.js and have an option for what you need.  Then everyone could benefit.  It would be relatively simple in d3, and it would match the solution I'm giving for your particular case fairly closely.

So, if you don't want to upstream a change, just [transform your data](https://jsfiddle.net/qk94cuaq/1/):

```
var dataDict = {};
data.forEach(function (item) {
    dataDict[item.Expt + '|' + item.Run] = item;
});
var dataCoalesced = [];
for (var expt = 1; expt <= 5; expt ++) {
    for (var run = 1; run <= 20; run ++) {
        dataCoalesced.push(dataDict[expt + '|' + run] || {
            Expt: expt,
            Run: run,
            Speed: 0,
        });
    }
}
```